# Turkish and German names for quarter tones

Tags: terminology, quarter-tones

I am interested in Turkish music and stumbled over quarter tones. Now I would love to be able to name those notes in Turkish and German but didn't find the respective ways to name those notes.

However, I managed to find the French and English names such as *Si demi-bémol*/*B half flat* or *Do demi-dièse*/*C half flat*, cf.

- [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altération_(musique)#Alt.C3.A9rations_quart-de-tonales](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt%C3%A9ration_(musique)#Alt.C3.A9rations_quart-de-tonales)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_(music)#Related_symbols
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp_(music)#Variants

What is the equivalent tone in Turkish and German?

Comment: Hm, I know very little about traditional Turkish music, but I strongly suspect that you’ll run into the fact that there are differences not merely in labels and terminology, but in concepts and structural approaches.

Comment: The whole idea of semitones / accidentals is rooted in Western common practice theory (which in the 19th century began to mean 12-edo tuning). Middle Eastern music works from fundamentally different principles, and although it is often explained in terms of "quarter tones" that's kind of a Western-eyed caricature. The proper turkish terms aren't goint to refer to quarter tones, but rather to various absolute scale degrees in the different makamlar. [Wikipedia actually has a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_makam#Notes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So the notation I saw on some sheets where e.g. the quarter-tone lowered note would have a mirrored flat symbol in front of it is a simplification to fit the note in Western notation?